# No way to access to internet conecting PC to hotspot wifi Android device

Tags: connection-issues, wifi-hotspot

My phone connects to internet properly. When activating Hotspot wifi, PC detects and reveices an optimal signal but there is no connection to internet at all. With other wifi signals it is properly working. Using USB the same happens. It seems that  Bluetooth connection is allowing access to internet but it is too slow. Any idea about how to make it work? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your phone only has one (1) WiFi chip.
This means it can only connect to one WiFi AP **or** act as a hotspot,
not both at once.

When you activate the WiFi hotspot, you get a warning, telling you that this will disconnect you from your current AP and use mobile data.